# Where can I summarize the solution provided by an answer?

Tags: discussion

I had a [tricky question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44730739/5135551) that was very nicely answered through a bit of back and forth. However, the question and answer were in "bits", and I had to pull it together into a small sample with tests to ensure it works. I'd like to share this working code as a replacement to my incorrect code in the original question. Where can I do that?

1. Add a "Solution" section to the end of my original question?
2. Add an answer with my solution, but giving well deserved credit to the original answer
3. Don't provide the solution at all (but that makes anyone interested in doing this to have to piece together the answer I have already done)

Comment: Have you considered making your post community wiki?

Comment: @AndrewLi It wouldn't be a collaborative work of multiple people, it would be his own answer, so using CW would be wrong.

Comment: If you have an _answer,_ why wouldn't you post it as an answer? You can make it community wiki so you don't get the rep for it. By "back and forth", I assume it was between you and another user, meaning it _is_ a collaborative work. (If it is just you piecing things together after playing with a given answer, I wouldn't mark it CW. You'd just be doing it to avoid the rep changes at that point, which is an abuse of the feature.)

Comment: @Servy Well, they mentioned there was a back and forth, so it was sort of collaborative. Also, they don't really want to get rep for it, so it seems appropriate.

Comment: @Kendra If you look at the post, there isn't actually a back and forth going on there.

Comment: I like to keep the answer together with the original work too. Otherwise it likely won't be found or more likely missed by someone that was referencing the original SO question.

Comment: @Servy I hadn't taken a look, but I did edit my comment to address that possibility.

Comment: @AndrewLi CW is not a way to just not get rep for a post.  It's a way of indicating that a post isn't authored by a single person, but rather a lot of people, and that others are also welcome to change the *content* of the post, because the post itself is intended to be updated as a wiki, rather than being one person's answer.  That's not what's going on here. This is simply one person having found an answer based in part on another answer, in which case the solution is to cite the work.  Also this user didn't specifically say that they don't want the rep (they didn't bring it up either way).

Comment: It took me an hour to digest his very helpful answer, write the test code to make it work. I would have loved to have found that originally.

Comment: Then I would post an answer with what you did, leave the other answer accepted, and call it good. Make sure you explain your answer. It might save someone else trouble later, if it took you a bit to be sure that answer worked.

Comment: Whatever you do, though, _don't_ add solutions to questions. There's a reason they're two separate sections on the page: To make it easier to read through the posts and figure out what's what.

Comment: @Kendra If you feel like the other answer isn't actually the best answer to the question (because you felt it was missing *that* much content) then it would be better to accept the new answer.  If you don't feel that the new answer is actually the better answer to the question, I don't know why you'd post it in the first place.

Comment: @Servy My answer is exactly the answer provided, but has the necessary code around it, including tests, to show how to use it. The option to add it to the end of the question is off the table though it seems. Fair enough.

Comment: @JimLeask I don't see how the context around the question related to how you intend to use the answer is going to be relevant to anyone else.  If the context isn't necessary for the question to be answered in the first place, I don't see why it would be helpful to add it now; it'd likely just be distracting.  As far as tests, I don't *personally* see that as being something that's important for SO answers (unless you've got one showing a problem with it); that also seems like something that's getting pretty off topic to the question in my opinion, but that *is* just an opinion.